# Leetcode - reverse linked list in python using recursion

Tags: python, recursion, linked-list

I am trying to solve this problem in leetcode :
https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-linked-list/

Using recursion, this is the solution I came up with:

```py
class Solution:
    def reverse(self,currpointer,nexthead):
        if not currpointer.next:
            print("final node",currpointer.val)
            currpointer.next = nexthead
            print("NOW WE RETURN")
            return currpointer
        else:
            print(f"Currpointer = {currpointer.val}")
            temp = currpointer.next
            print("temp val = ",temp.val)
            currpointer.next = nexthead
            return self.reverse(temp,currpointer)
    def reverseList(self, head: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
        return self.reverse(head,None)
```

The problem I encounter is that the recursion does not stop at the base cases, using the prints I have :

```
temp val =  2
Currpointer = 2
temp val =  3
Currpointer = 3
temp val =  4
Currpointer = 4
temp val =  5
final node 5
NOW WE RETURN
Currpointer = 1
temp val =  2
final node 2
NOW WE RETURN
```

Why does it not stop at the base case, but instead keeps running?

Comment: You are mislead by the LeetCode framework. It executes **two** test cases, and the output you see is the *combined* output.

Comment: So the prints after the 'now we return' are just the prints from the second test case?

Comment: That's what I am saying yes. You can easily debug that by printing something at the start of your `reverseList` method, before calling the recursive helper. Then you see when LeetCode is calling your `reverseList` method...

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, I didn't know that's how it works and was thinking my use of self and inner function is the problem.